# What is electrolytic protection?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

My highschool textbook tells me that sacrificial protection (more technically-cathodic protection) and electrolytic protection are different. I have searched high and low for an explanation of electrolytic protection, but I got nothing.

It describes the electrolytic protection, stating that the steel/iron structure is hooked up to an electrolytic (not electrochemical!) cell as the negative terminal (cathode) and the anode is an inert material (titanium, in the example).

Why does this work, if it does at all?

Comment: Electrolytic protection and sacrificial protection are synonymous, in my opinion. It is obtained by applying a layer of zinc metal on a piece of iron exposed to rain. The iron piece will not get oxidized, because zinc will be oxidized before iron.

Comment: The world would be rather different without CP .Nat gas piped to homes, etc, would be rare. Many would not have water piped to homes ; many municipalites do not apply CP and hope for the best with their cast iron pipe , just replace as needed , the taxpayers will pay for it. Gasoline and plastics would be much more expensive because of transportation costs . I hoped a high school science text would not be so incompetent . But not surprised after looking at the local university chemistry. text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand why a HS text might call it "electrolytic" , but in the real world it is called "cathodic protection" or CP. That is what to look for on the net. It is a multibillion dollar industry. Essentially all pipelines ( oil, gas, products, water , etc.) use it . A large majority off offshore steel structures ( oil  platforms, ships, etc) use it. And many steel products are galvanized . There are two basic types ; sacrificial coatings and impressed current. Sacrificial coatings are represented by galvanized steel , also aluminum and cadmium coatings. Impressed current, CP is also  two categories : Sacrificial anodes , usually aluminum ( which do not use rectifiers) , and inert anodes , usually titanium or graphite. These are buried in soils made more conductive with graphite powder (typically) and electrically connected to rectifiers  which are then connected to the steel to be protected . The voltage is adjusted and monitored along the protected steel , eg. pipeline. Pipelines are coated with an electrically insulating coating to reduce the amount of current required to maintain a protective voltage , normally lower than - 0.65 V ( Cu - Cu SO4 half cell) Too low a voltage can cause hydrogen gas bubbles under the coating and hydrogen embrittlement of certain steels.There is also anodic protection but it has very specific limited applications. So, there is such a thing as "electrolytic" protection.

Comment: How do those impressed current systems actually prevent corrosion? As long as there is any oxygen close to the metal (especially in conductive soils/waters), you can have a "side reaction" of surface corrosion/rust formation, completely separate from whatever flow of electricity from the CP-system...

Comment: An over simplification is the CP raises the voltage of the steel so the oxygen emf is not strong enough to take any electrons.

Comment: But voltage relative to what? The oxygen that exists everywhere in the conductive soil/water environment  anyway (which actually causes the corrosion), or just to some random distant anode installed somewhere else? Having a cathodic voltage merely relative to the latter seems pointless -- it's the oxygen omnipresent everywhere in the conductive soil/water environment that causes the corrosion. How would having a voltage relative to some distant anode in a specific location protect against that?

Comment: Electrolysis anodes can only protect metal cathodes from oxidants present nearby the anode surfaces. In other words, for example, establishing a voltage difference between a steel cathode and some distant graphite (or whatever) anode ([this is what impressed current (ICCP) diagrams often seem to look like anyway!](https://www.sestech.in/images/CorrCAD1.gif)) does *not* automatically also establish a significant voltage difference between that same steel cathode, and other oxygen molecules that instead exist next to the surface of the cathode, as well.

Comment: CP is such a large industry you can get all the info you want on the net under cathodic protection.

Comment: Interesting, it seems I was quite overestimating the rate of rust formation / oxidation on the metal parts in those conductive soil/water environments anyway. If ICCP is able to deter / slow down corrosion and/or somewhat lessen its dangerous effects even somewhat, it could still be quite a useful investment...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know sacrificial protection refers to the protection of iron specifically, while electrolytic protection is for all metals.

The concept of electrolytic protection is that a valuable metal is connected with an invaluable and more reactive one to create an electrolytic cell. The invaluable is the anode as it is more reactive and it gets oxidized by the environment, while the less reactive valuable metal forms the cathod and is protected from oxidization.

**A note :** Electrochemical cells are cells that produce electricity and cells that electricity is applied to them. Electrolytic cells are cells that electricity is applied to them. So they are not exactly the same thing.